# How to build opencv_contrib module for iOS

Tags: opencv, cmake

I want to use some function in the newly introduced opencv_contrib modules on iOS, how can I build a iOS framework with those extra modules. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean opencv_contrib ? (opencv_extra holds the data needed for the unittests)

Comment: yes, I mean open_contrib. I need the ximgproc module in it.

Comment: apple hater here, can't help you ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The official document does not include building iOS framework with opencv_contrib.

But inferring from the cmake file, you can copy the module you want (ximgproc in your case) to opencv/modules. Then run build_framework.py as usual.

You can checkout this [post](http://xfanzone.me/opencv-for-ios-en.html)

Comment: Link asks to install browser extension

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this (old) question for the benefit of other developers who would like to try this on newer OpenCV versions.

It is possible to build opencv_contrib modules together with the iOS framework, in version 4 (current at the time of answering).

1. set path to the Xcode command line tools:

   sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer Developer
2. cd to the path above the opencv directory

   cd ~/
3. Build the framework with the --contrib option:

   python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py --contrib <'relative_path_to_opencv_contrib'>/opencv_contrib/ ios

If an individual module does not get build, you should check the CMakelists.txt of that module to see if it has been disabled for iOS.

I just tested this before answering, so feel free to drop a comment or a question if there are issues.

Answer (score 1):

See fficial document [tutorial_ios_install](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/da3/tutorial_ios_install.html)!
This works well.

Comment: This is the way to build OpenCV for iOS with contrib. (Link to official site documentation). Accepted answer should be reconsidered